# CodeIgniter Model Call to Model

Tags: codeigniter, model

Im using CodeIgniter 2.0.2 and I noticed while calling a Model from within a Model, you dont need to load it.

For instance, in a Controller you need to write

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$this->my_model->my_function();
```

But in a Model it can load just like this

```
$this->my_model->my_function();
```

Should i avoid writing my code like this, or is this safe?

Comment: I'm not sure about the inner workings of CI, but are you sure you just didn't load that model in the controller? I think that should make it available to other models loaded in that context

Comment: @danneth - ahh yes, that must be what it is. okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid writing my code like this, but for a different reason.

Models are generally loaded from controllers, so it seems strange that you would need one model to call another one. Are you sure that there is not a better way to structure your code, such as having a model base class or using a helper for common functionality?

Comment: Im sure thous are better ways of going about this task. Im new to CodeIgniter and Model-View-Controller in general. Thanks for the answer.